# ViewPager addOnPageChangeListener not working on same tabClick

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a `ViewPager` with `addOnPageChangeListener`. `ViewPager` has 3 tabviews (tab1, tab2, tab3). When a user clicks tab2, it loads some data (Basically it a `RecyclerView`). At this moment, if user again clicks tab2, I need to reload the data but in this case `addOnPageChangeListener` is not triggered.

My Code:

```
customPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), MainActivity.this);
viewPager.setAdapter(customPagerAdapter);

viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }

    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        Log.i("TAG", "position: " + position);
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                addingMarker(LocationData.find(LocationData.class, "Category = ? ", "1"));
                break;
            case 1:
                addingMarker(LocationData.find(LocationData.class, "Category = ? ", "2"));
                break;
            case 2:
                addingMarker(LocationData.find(LocationData.class, "Category = ? ", "3"));
                break;
        }
    }
});
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

Comment: `OnPageChangeListener` is triggered when "page is changed". Are you using `TabLayout` for the tabs?

Comment: Yes I am using tablayout

Comment: Updated my code please check it'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

The Android team has changed a few things about how TabLayout and ViewPager talk to each other. [Read the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html). But things are not explained well. I've included a lot of comments in the code. I hope that helps.

```
final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

// the tabs will get their titles from the adapter and get populated
tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);

// this is done "so that the tab position is kept in sync"
// what it does is when you swipe the fragment in view pager, it updates the tabs
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

// without this listener the tabs would still get updated when fragments are swiped, but ....  (read the next comment)
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tabSelected:  " + tab.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // no where in the code it is defined what will happen when tab is tapped/selected by the user
        // this is why the following line is necessary
        // we need to manually set the correct fragment when a tab is selected/tapped
        // and this is the problem in your code
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tabReSelected:  " + tab.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Reload your recyclerView here
    }
});
```

Check out this [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=3035) if you have got any other problems.

**EDIT 1: December 2015**

**Not a solution to this question but helpful in general.**

```
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

This way you don't need to worry about setting the fragment yourself when a tab is selected. `tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(..)` is no longer needed in this situation. That is handled [under the hood](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java#743). This is useful when you don't need too much control over your tabs(like reloading fragment when same tab is selected/tapped).

**UPDATE: MAY 2018**

```
tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(...);
```

Both of the above functions are deprecated. Initialize viewpager+tablayout as shown below:

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager); // this will automatically bind tab clicks to viewpager fragments
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout))

// do additional tab clicks here
// no need to manually set viewpager item based on tab click
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your `onPageSelected` callback is not being called because the page isn't actually changing. I think if you write a custom subclass of `TabLayout.ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener`, you can use the `onTabReselected` callback to trigger your refresh even those the selected page index hasn't changed.

You should be able to install your custom `OnTabSelectedListener` using `TabLayout::setOnTabSelectedListener` ***after*** you call `setupWithViewPager`.