# ViewPagerFragment Tab Error

Tags: android, android-fragments

i create a viewPager and is work , my problem is for select a page i just can drag page but I want to click on the tabs to select the pages . now i add some new code but i cant find this error

[image]

my code

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    Pager adapter = new Pager(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    viewPager.addOnAdapterChangeListener( new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));




    TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener tabListener = new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    };
```

Comment: try this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34271137/viewpager-addonpagechangelistener-not-working-on-same-tabclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant use like `viewPager.addOnAdapterChangeListener( new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));` Because  `addOnAdapterChangeListener()` method  expect `OnAdapterChangeListener` as paramenter. You should use `void addOnPageChangeListener (ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener)` on `viewPager`  instead.It has several [callback method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html), So you can detect the `event` when page of `viewPager` is changed.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#addOnPageChangeListener(android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener))